# String.Split() for a array of string's 2nd value is not saving to new variable

Tags: java, regex, split

Everything is reading for example the values of lines[] but when i am trying to save it in a variable it is not saving the 2nd value. like lines[1] is saving but lines[2] is not saving.

```
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            lines = line.split("[:,]");

            for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                if(lines.length > 0) {
                    if(lines[0].contains("x")||lines[0].contains("y")) {
                        double x = Double.parseDouble(lines[1]);
                        double y = Double.parseDouble(lines[2]);
                    }
```

Comment: what is your input and your expected output?

Comment: why post your code here again?  Edit your question with the information that is requested

Comment: its not saving the value in y. from debug i am able to see it is saving the value in x but when debuger pointer is crossing y nothing is getting saved into it. and it is getting back to the while loop and looking for new line.

Comment: what is your input and your expected output?  what is the value of `lines[2]`   You have no code the break out the loop  .  also `x` and `y` are local to your `if` block

Comment: the third elements of the lines array.

Comment: while loop will terminate when next line is null. there is no problem in the while loop terminator. also this is not the issue of local variable. the value of y is not even showing in the expression of the debugger..

Comment: Is it possible that `lines.length <= 2`, and thus `lines[2]` causes an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` to be thrown?

Comment: @KevinAnderson how? as this array length is 3. so if we put lines.length<=2 it will not execute the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

if I initialize the value of x and y initially then y is getting the value. I do not know why do i need to initialize? But i would like to know further...

package com.inputOutput;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RealMadrid {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    double x=0;
    double y=0;
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("english.txt"));
    String[] lines = null;

    try {
        String line;
        while ((line= reader.readLine()) != null) {
            lines = line.split("[:,]");

            int i =0;
            if(lines.length>0){
                if(lines[0].contains("x")||lines[0].contains("y")) {
                     x = Double.parseDouble(lines[1]);
                     y = Double.parseDouble(lines[2]);
                }
            }
        }
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

}